# Calling dlopen from a shared library loaded via JNI makes previously loaded symbols invisible

Tags: java, java-native-interface, dlopen

I have a Java application which interacts with native code using JNI. The native code compiles a file at runtime and attempts to load this file using a *dlopen* call. This call fails and I get a warning stating

`Could not load library (x):(x) undefined symbol: y`

However when I have a native application starting a JVM via JNI run the same code, this error does not occur and it runs as expected. I am suspecting Java is doing something fancy which causes the already loaded libraries to be invisible for the library that is loaded with *dlopen*.

This I did to diagnose the problem:

- Confirmed in which shared library the symbol that was supposedly undefined is located using `objdump`
- Confirmed this library is loaded by using `gdb` (via eclipse - the library was listed in the modules pane)
- Printed LD_LIBRARY_PATH just before the dlopen and confirmed Java passes it through (It did add Java's lib dirs but the original dirs were still there)

I have been trying to solve this for a while now, but I can't figure out what is going on. Especially because it does work when the JVM is loaded from a native application.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've never had a problem using `dlopen` from JNI.  What OS is this?  Where is this `y` symbol defined?  Are you sure that the JVM is loading whatever library contains `y`?

Comment: Yes, like I said I confirmed in which library symbol y is defined using `objdump -x | grep y` and checked the JVM is loading it using `gdb`. The OS is Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit. I am running a `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)` with `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)`. I also confirmed the library that is supposed to be loaded is 64-bit as well.

Comment: I think my problem has something to do with -export-dynamic flag of libtool. However I tried setting this and it does not seem to fix the problem. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer. The solution was to recompile the shared library that contained the symbol that was not found with the `-Wl,--export-dynamic` linker flag.

Interestingly I did not program that shared library myself and I would expect the default compilation to add the flag since it was needed for software using it to function properly.

Either way it is a open source project so I could compile it with the **proper flags set**.

Comment: I am compiling `GSL` library via `./configure` command. Where should i put this linker option?

Comment: Could you please explain what you think the two flags are doing?